# How can I set a lock inside a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, stored-procedures

I've got a long-running stored procedure on a SQL server database. I don't want it to run more often than once every ten minutes.

Once the stored procedure has run, I want to store the latest result in a `LatestResult` table, against a time, and have all calls to the procedure return that result for the next ten minutes.

That much is relatively simple, but we've found that, because the procedure checks the `LatestResult` table and updates it, that large userbases are getting a number of deadlocks, when two users call the procedure at the same time.

In a client-side/threading situation, I would solve this by using a lock, having the first user lock the function, the second user encounters the lock, waiting for the result, the first user finishes their procedure call, updates the `LatestResult` table, and unlocks the second user, who then picks up the result from the `LatestResult` table.

Is there any way to accomplish this kind of locking in SQL Server?

**EDIT:**

This is basically how the code looks without its error checking calls:

```
DECLARE @LastChecked AS DATETIME
DECLARE @LastResult AS NUMERIC(18,2)
SELECT TOP 1 @LastChecked = LastRunTime, @LastResult = LastResult FROM LastResult

DECLARE @ReturnValue AS NUMERIC(18,2)

IF DATEDIFF(n, @LastChecked, GetDate()) >= 10 OR NOT @LastResult = 0
BEGIN 
    SELECT @ReturnValue = ABS(ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(Amount,0)),0)) FROM Transactions WHERE ISNULL(DeletedFlag,0) = 0 GROUP BY GroupID ORDER BY ABS(ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(Amount,0)),0))
        UPDATE LastResult SET LastRunTime = GETDATE(), LastResult = @ReturnValue
        SELECT @ReturnValue
    END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @LastResult
END
```

I'm not really sure what's going on with the grouping, but I've found a test system where execution time is coming in around 4 seconds.

I think there's some work scheduled to archive some of these records and boil them down to running totals, which will probably help things given that there's several million rows in that four second table...

Comment: This seems like an elaborate plan to deal with a slow running stored proc.  How much effort has been put into optimizing the SP?

Comment: It basically runs SUM() over most of the values in a column, but it's a big column, and we need the value quite often. Personally I'd just call SUM(), but presumably the procedure was put in by a previous employee for a reason other than to be awkward and cause deadlocks. It's not a great justification, but it's all I've got, sadly.

Comment: Can you post some tsql code?

Comment: Done, posted. Character limit.

Comment: Aside from the question there is a glaring issue with this code. The first statement has select top 1 but there is no order by which means you have no guarantee which row you are going to get.

Comment: And there is no need for an order by when setting ReturnValue, it is an aggregate so calculating the value is again is double the work for no gain.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really sure about that part, myself.

Comment: This could surely be made to go a bit faster. The nonSARGable predicate ISNULL(DeletedFlag, 0) = 0 could be improved. There are many things in here that would improved the performance and accuracy of this. Can you put up a sqlfiddle for this? Also, what is LastNominalBalanceFound? There must be more to this proc that you haven't posted.

Comment: `SUM` (and other aggregate functions) ignore `NULL`s, so you could eliminate most of the `ISNULL` function calls.  I'm not sure if you'll get a performance boost from this (the optimizer may be sophisticated enough on its own to ignore the unneeded calls to `ISNULL`)...but the code will be a bit cleaner.

Comment: Pulling the grouping and the ordering shaves about 75% off the execution time. That much will probably vastly cut down on the problems people are encountering with this function. How odd that they're even there in the first place...

Comment: @Frosty840 : are you sure about the `OR NOT @LastResult = 0` condition? It seems that would cause it to do the update immediately upon being updated, right?

Comment: @srutzky : In practice we actually want the whole thing to sum out to 0, so if the total isn't 0, we check properly every time the function is run so that the function always returns the current value, so that the users aren't waiting for the ten minute timer to run out.

Comment: @Frosty840 : ok, then doesn't that mean the ELSE condition is essentially `SELECT 0` since you can't get there if @LastResult is not zero, right?

Comment: @srutzky : I agree with that assessment.

Comment: @Frosty840 : ok, so then the original logic, outside of the multithreading issue we are dealing with, doesn't seem to live up to your needs since if the value is not 0, then this code (the getting a new value and setting it as LastResult) will run for each thread until it finally hits zero. And in that time, it will keep updating the LastChecked timer but that is meaningless until the value is 0. Something seems odd here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a valid opportunity to use an Application Lock (see [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) and [sp_releaseapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178602.aspx)) as it is a lock taken out on a concept that you define, not on any particular rows in any given table.  The idea is that you create a transaction, then create this arbitrary lock that has an indetifier, and other processes will wait to enter that piece of code until the lock is released. This works just like `lock()` at the app layer. The `@Resource` parameter is the label of the arbitrary "concept". In more complex situations, you can even concatenate a CustomerID or something in there for more granular locking control.

```sql
DECLARE @LastChecked DATETIME,
        @LastResult NUMERIC(18,2);
DECLARE @ReturnValue NUMERIC(18,2);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = 'check_timing', @LockMode = 'Exclusive';

SELECT TOP 1 -- not sure if this helps the optimizer on a 1 row table, but seems ok
       @LastChecked = LastRunTime,
       @LastResult = LastResult
FROM LastResult;

IF (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @LastChecked, GETDATE()) >= 10 OR @LastResult <> 0)
BEGIN 
   SELECT @ReturnValue = ABS(ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(Amount, 0)), 0))
   FROM   Transactions
   WHERE  DeletedFlag = 0
   OR     DeletedFlag IS NULL;

   UPDATE LastResult
   SET    LastRunTime = GETDATE(),
          LastResult = @ReturnValue;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
   SET @ReturnValue = @LastResult; -- This is always 0 here
END;

SELECT @ReturnValue AS [ReturnValue];

EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'check_timing';
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

You need to manage errors / ROLLBACK yourself (as stated in the linked MSDN documentation) so put in the usual TRY / CATCH.  But, this does allow you to manage the situation.

If there are any concerns regarding contention on this process, there shouldn't be much as the lookup done right after locking the resource is a SELECT from a single-row table and then an IF statement that (ideally) just returns the last known value if the 10-minute timer hasn't elapsed. Hence, most calls should process rather quickly.

**Please note:** `sp_getapplock` / `sp_releaseapplock` should be used sparingly; Application Locks can definitely be very handy (such as in cases like this one) but they should only be used when absolutely necessary.

Comment: FYI... the default behaviour here is for the Lock to be Transaction scoped, so it will be automatically released when this transaction is Committed or Rolled-back, so the call to `sp_releaseapplock` is not necessary.